# Wanting to get rid of the Test Hub in TFS and integrate with Test Rail

Tags: testing, tfs, api-design, test-suite, testrail

Just wondering if there is a way to integrate TFS with TestRail to replace(get rid of entirely) the Test Hub within TFS to use TestRail to record Test Plans?
My concern with removing the Test Hub, would be if Test Rail can still reference IDs in Bug and Stories within TFS and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

You currently cannot remove the standard Hubs in Visual Studio Team Services / TFS or replace them with something else. You can enable an extension that either adds its own functionality under said hub as a separate tab or adds another Test Rail hub to the top level (if there is any) or write your own. Extensions currently cannot leave their sandbox to overwrite standard functionality.

There is nothing preventing anything from keeping track of work item numbers anywhere, so the second part of your question, whether it would have broken any form of integrations, that's unlikely.

If you are on TFS, you could try creating a custom process template that doesn't have the Test Case, Shared Step, Test Suite and Test Plan work item types, this will likely at least completely cripple the existing functionality. In the on-prem version you can also customize the files on disk, I've never tried, but it's likely that you could probably hack the test hub away. That would be a totally unsupported scenario through.